# Low speed with GSM Mobile on ubuntu

Tags: internet-connection

I use nokia 5200 mobile for internet but its speed in ubuntu is very low as compared to that of windows xp. Pls help me how to increase net speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the problem with Ubuntu, because i also use Nokia 5233 to connect to Internet and my Internet speed is almost same on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7. May be it is because you may have programs on Ubuntu which uses Internet connection( e.g RSS Reader, Weather Widget etc) and decreases overall speed of your connection.